# How to Responsive View for Card using MUI Breakpoints without xs,sx,md ,lg & xl?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, breakpoints

**How to reduce so many breakpoints?** I need a card height for all responsive views.

Using xs, sx, md, lg & xl so many height spaces.
 But I can't achieve it using this xs,sx,md,lg &xl.So I used MUI breakpoints between & size.

[image: I Try this]

Answer (score 1):

MUI has a customisable theme now (including breakpoints) for react.js see documentation on creating your own breakpoints:

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints

You could change them from this...

```
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1536,
    },
  },
});
```

To this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 640,
      laptop: 1024,
      desktop: 1200,
    },
  },
});
```